# $\forall C \subseteq A$, $\exists C' \subseteq A : C \subseteq D \Rightarrow C' \subseteq D'$ then $\exists E \subseteq A : E = E'$

Tags: general-topology

**Theorem**: Suppose that with each subset $C$ of $A$ there is associated a subset $C'$ of $A$ in such a way that $C \subseteq D$ implies $C' \subseteq D'$. Then $E = E'$ for some $E \subseteq A$.

**Scratch**: The hint for this problem was: Let $E =\displaystyle \bigcup_{C \subseteq C'} C$.

I can easily get: $(E \subseteq E')$: Let $x \in E$, then by definition $x \in C$ for some $C \in \mathcal P(A)$ such that $C \subseteq C'$. Observe that $C \subseteq E$ and by hypothesis $C' \subseteq E'$. But $x \in C \subseteq C' \subseteq E'$ so $x \in E'$. Conclude that $E \subseteq E'$.

I am not able to get the other inclusion: $(E' \subseteq E)$. I tried to suppose by way of contradiction that there was an element not in the set, then it cannot be in any $C$ such that $C \subseteq C'$. I am not sure what to do.

Note: This is a problem from Willard's General Topology, it is supposed to be the first step in outlining a proof of the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem. (Sub-Note: I am *not* looking for a proof of that, I'm looking for a solution to *this* problem.)

Comment: This looks particularly close to the Tarski-Knaster Fixed-point Theorem.

Comment: How are $D$ and $D'$ quantified?

Comment: You may want to leave out $\exists C' \subseteq A$ from the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $E\subseteq E'$ therefore $E'\subseteq E''$. So in the union defining $E$ we have $E'$ as one of the sets.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: It happens! :-)