# Question about partially ordering sets using the containment relation and order preserving functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a non-empty set $A$ and a partial ordering of $P(A)$ by the containment relation, given an order preserving $f: P(A)\to P(A)$, show that there exists a $B$ such that $f(B)=B$.

So far my thoughts are as follows:
The minimal element in the group $P(A)$ ordered by containment has to be $[\emptyset]$, but I'm not sure where that gets me.

Also, can I say that  $[\emptyset]$ is contained in $f([\emptyset])$?

I'm not sure how to coninute, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I definitely answered that a week ago. Also known as the Knaster-Tarski fixed point theorem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655044/forall-c-subseteq-a-exists-c-subseteq-a-c-subseteq-d-rightarrow-c/ should give you enough to go for.